# I need some help with a GCD and LCM's Problem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

Given a list $A$ of $n$ positive integer numbers. We're gonna play this game:

> $1 -$ Take randomly $2$ numbers of $A$.
>
> $2 -$ Delete this $2$ elements of $A$.
>
> $3 -$ Insert in $A$ their gcd and lcm.
>
> $4 -$ Go to step $1.$

Prove that after some quantity of steps, $A$ doesn't change its elements.

Comment: Hint: at each step $\min A$ decreases or stays the same, and $\max A$ increases or stays the same. At some point $\min A$ will be the $\gcd$ of all integers in $A$, and $\max A$ will be their $\operatorname{lcm}$.

Comment: @dxiv:  that is a great hint and I think it should be an answer

Comment: I know that, at some point the list would have just 2 different numbers, the gcd and the lcm of all numbers in the initial list. But I don't know how prove that.

Comment: @JoseA132:  If you know that, you should say it so people can know what sort of answer is useful.  How do you know it?  That is also helpful

Comment: Its not necessary that the list will have only two different numbers. There can be many different number but for each $a_i<a_j$, $a_i|a_j$ i.e. $a_i$ divides $a_j$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks, but it was just that, a hint. There is enough work left to do proving that the stationary point is where $\{a,b\}=\{\gcd(a,b),\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\}$ for $\forall a,b \in A$ that my hint doesn't qualify as an answer.

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}$Note that at each stage the product $P$ of all the numbers stays the same, as $a b = \gcd(a, b) \lcm(a, b)$. The sum of the numbers stays the same if the chosen pair is $a, b$ with $a \le b$, say, and $a \mid b$, so that $a = \gcd(a, b)$ and $b = \lcm(a, b)$. The sum increases if $a \le b$, say, and $a \nmid b$, as then $\lcm(a, b) \ge 2 b \ge a + b$. Now the sum cannot exceed $n P$, therefore the process must stop (with probability $1$).

Comment: Just to clarify, the last inequality is $\operatorname{lcm}(a, b) \ge 2 b > a + b$.

Comment: This also shows that in the final, stationary state, you have a sequence that can be reordered to $a_1, \dots, a_n$, such that $a_i$ divides  $a_{i+1}$ for each   $I. $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}$I will concoct my comments into an answer.

Note that at each step, when dealing with the terms $a, b$ of the list, the product $P$ of all the terms of the list remains constant, as
$$
a b = \gcd(a, b) \cdot \lcm(a, b).
$$

As to the sum of the terms of the list, if $a \le b$, say, and $a \mid b$, then it does not change, as
$$
a = \gcd(a, b), \quad b = \lcm(a, b).
$$
However, if $a \le b$ and $a \nmid b$ (so that $a < b$) then
$$
\gcd(a, b) + \lcm(a, b)
>
\lcm(a, b)
\ge 
2b
> a + b,
$$
so the sum of the terms of the list has increased (by at least $2$).

Since the sum of the terms of the list can be at most $n P$, the process must terminate (with probability $1$, say).

In the final state, we will have that if $a \le b$ are two terms in the list, then $a \mid b$. That is, once the list is reordered in non-decreasing order as
$$
a_1 \le a_2 \le \dots \le a_n,
$$
we will have that $a_i$ divides $a_{i+1}$ for each $i$.

Comment: @miracle173, thanks! I can tell you nearly exactly where I learned the term, from a talk by Otto Kegel in Rome, I think it was 1973.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Can you explain me why the sum of the terms of the list can be at most $nP$?

Comment: Each term is less than or equal to the product of all terms.

Comment: @JoseA132 This is essentially one of the standard ways of reducing a diagonal matrix to [Smith Normal Form.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form)

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Thanks for your help. Of course is that, I haven't see it.